# Map and reduce array of objects with a children array down to array of children with parent's id

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lambda

I'm  trying to take an array of objects like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId1",
    "children": [
      {
        "childProp1": "test1",
        "childProp2": "test3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId2",
    "children": [
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
      },
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And return an array of all the children combined, with each child object having an additional value, the "id" of the parent.

Above examples, result.

```
[
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
    "childProp1": "test1",
    "childProp2": "test3"
  },
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals",
    "childProp2": "other vals"
  }
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals 1",
    "childProp2": "other vals 1"
  }
]
```

I'm just not sure how to approach this. I'm familiar with flattening and array of arrays. But I'm only able to get the output as an array of the original children without adding the parentId

Comment: shorter titles that explain more FTW

Comment: dont know how to explain it any shorter

Comment: eg `Howto use Map reduce to reorganise an array of objects`.  As soon as you mentioned: parents, children, id's, it thought i was reading your description, not your title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var values = [{
    "id": "uniqueParentId1",
    "children": [{
      "childProp1": "test1",
      "childProp2": "test3"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId2",
    "children": [{
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
      },
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var result = values.map(value =>
  value.children.map(child => ({ parentId: value.id, ...child }))
).flat();

console.log(result);
```

A breakdown of the code:

```
child => ({ parentId: value.id , ...child })
```

Takes an object and returns a new object with the `parentId` property and all of the properties in `child`.

Input:

```
{
    "childProp1": "somevals",
    "childProp2": "other vals"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2"
    "childProp1": "somevals",
    "childProp2": "other vals"
}
```

Next function:

```
value =>
    value.children.map(child => ({ parentId: value.id, ...child }))
```

Takes an object named `value`, applies the function above to each of the array elements in `value.children`, and returns an array of the results.

Next:

```
values.map(.....)
```

Applies the function above to each of the elements in `values` and returns an array of the results.

At this point, the result of this `.map()` call is an array like the following, with one element for each element of the original array:

```
[
  [
    {
      "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
      "childProp1": "test1",
      "childProp2": "test3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
      "childProp1": "somevals",
      "childProp2": "other vals"
    },
    {
      "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
      "childProp1": "somevals 1",
      "childProp2": "other vals 1"
    }
  ]
]
```

So the last thing we do is flatten flatten this array with `.flat()`.

Comment: Like your solution! Maybe add a few lines explaining your code, so other people not as familiar with functional js can understand your solution?

Comment: @AP. Thanks for the suggestion. Added an explanation, but it turned out to be more than a few lines. :)

Comment: Great solution, thanks! How would you do this if there are multiple nested arrays/objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId1",
    "children": [
      {
        "childProp1": "test1",
        "childProp2": "test3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "uniqueParentId2",
    "children": [
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals",
        "childProp2": "other vals"
      },
      {
        "childProp1": "somevals 1",
        "childProp2": "other vals 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];
let combined = [];
arr.forEach((parent) => {
  const {id, children} = parent;
  children.forEach((child) => {
    Object.assign(child, {
      parentId: id
    });
    combined.push(child);
  });
});

console.log(combined);
/*
[
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId1",
    "childProp1": "test1",
    "childProp2": "test3"
  },
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals",
    "childProp2": "other vals"
  }
  {
    "parentId": "uniqueParentId2",
    "childProp1": "somevals 1",
    "childProp2": "other vals 1"
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a more functional approach, you can do something like:

```
const results = [] //Array we want to store all data in
arr.forEach(e => {
  const {id: parentId} = e  //Extract id as variable parentId

  // Store all the children objects with the added key
  e.children.forEach(c => results.push(Object.assign({parentId}, c)))
})
```