# C#/Javascript: How to convert JSON string contains parents-child array into multiple parents?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'd like to split parents-child array into multiple parents with one child.  The `JSON string` as below:

```
[{
   "Father-Name" : "Jack",
   "Mother-Name" : "Rose",
   "Children": [{ "Name" : "Lmao" }, {"Name" : "Lol"}]
},
{
   "Father-Name" : "Donald",
   "Mother-Name" : "Melissa",
   "Children": null
}]
```

and my desired output:

```
[{
   "Father-Name" : "Jack",
   "Mother-Name" : "Rose",
   "Children": { "Name" : "Lmao" }
},
{
   "Father-Name" : "Jack",
   "Mother-Name" : "Rose",
   "Children": {"Name" : "Lol"}
},
{
   "Father-Name" : "Donald",
   "Mother-Name" : "Melissa",
   "Children": null
}]
```

I did some searching but there's no matching for this.

Comment: Are you using javascript or c#? Also, please show what you have tried.

Comment: I prefer c#. I was going to de-serialize JSON string into a list of objects and loop through subitem then add new item to list base on subitem. It's just a thought. But I think performance will be bad.

Comment: That sounds like a fine plan, I don't think performance will be bad.

Comment: if it's Javascript could you pleases advise the best way to covert? Because the data will be displayed to end-user and I think it's better to process at client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this link [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740484/map-and-reduce-array-of-objects-with-a-children-array-down-to-array-of-children). Thanks to @JLRishe

I only modified a null check.

```js
var data = [{
   "Father" : "Jack",
   "Mother" : "Rose",
   "Children": [{ "Name" : "Lmao" }, {"Name" : "Lol"}]
},
{
   "Father" : "Donald",
   "Mother" : "Melissa",
   "Children": null
}]

var result = data.map(d => d.Children!== null ? d.Children.map(c => ({"Father": d.Father,"Mother": d.Mother, Children: {...c}})) : d).flat();

console.log(result);
```